# stop Mail.app opening in split-fullscreen

Tags: macos, mail.app, mojave, fullscreen

When I am within a full-screened app and I get a (new email) notification from Mail, if I click it it opens in half the screen (split vertically) instead of opening in a new window on another desktop.

How do I stop Mail from using this split-screen view for

- notifications
- composing new emails
- etc.

I tried following the steps described in this answer https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/354056/150109

Unchecking the "Prefer opening messages in split view when in full screen" preference.

[image]

But that doesn't seem to have changed anything.

Comment: That is a bug. There have been discussions about it on the site in at least 5 questions on the site AFAIK. One of them was mine, one has 54 votes, one is about investigations, and two are simply just like your question. So better to participate there. :)